# Set the second option value according to the first option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table. And I dynamically add rows to the table using jquery.
Each row has 3 select tag. I want to set the value of third option as same as the second one selected.

Here is my code:

```
$('#table tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('select:eq(1)').change(function () {

        var selectedVal = $("#table").find('select:eq(1)').val();
        $('#table').find('select:eq(2)').val(selectedVal);

    });
});
```

But my problem is it just worked for only one row. What wrong with my code?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLzvrbuw/)

Comment: Super classic dynamic stuff question... use event delegation : `$(document).on('change', 'select:eq(1)', function...` Will work for present and future `select` elements.

Comment: This is not a well formed question. I was very close to voting to close it if it weren't for the answers having some value. Just for future reference "What wrong with my code?" Is a sure way to get a question closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate event and use as selector `tr td:nth-child(2) select`:

```
$('#table').on('change', 'tr td:nth-child(2) select', function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('select:eq(2)').val(this.value);
 });
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 3):

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamic events.

```
$('#table').on('change', 'tr select:nth-child(1)',function() {   
    //traverse to  the parent row
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    //Find the second select
    var secondSelect = tr.find('select:eq(2)');

    //Set value
    secondSelect.val($(this).val());
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cvbvkxe2/)</kbd>

Comment: `select:eq(1)` would only target the second SELECT element. I think OP wants e.g: `'tr td:nth-child(2) select'` as selector http://jsfiddle.net/sj55njjL/3

Answer (score 0):

First off:

```
var selectedVal = $("#table").find('select:eq(1)').val();
```

should probably be:

```
var selectedVal = $(this).find('select:eq(1)').val();
```

else you are only getting the first row's select...

But a little nicer might be:

```
 $('#table tr').each(function(iter, elem) {                                     
     $(elem).find('select:eq(1)').change(function(){

         var selectedVal=$(this).val();
         $('#table').find('select:eq(2)').val(selectedVal);

    });
});
```